# Interpolation in a distorted box

Tags: math

I want to interpolate in a distorted box. As We have 8 points around a distorted box `(p0, p1, p2, ..., p7)`, if we find the transformation matrix which transform this box to a box with points `((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0) )`, the interpolation can be done easily. In other words, If we find a transformation from a distorted box to a normal box which length, width and height of the box are equal to 1, the interpolation can be done very simple. Anyone has any idea about interpolating in a distorted box or finding transformation from a distorted box to a normal box?

Comment: What does that have to do with C++?

Comment: In general there is no such transformation. A transformation in the affine space in R^3 has 12 unknowns (9 deformation + 3 translation), whereas your problem has 24 constraints( 3 x 8 points).

Comment: @sbabbi yes! I was thinking about it! so, there should many different transformations not a unique one. I want to find a way to get one of them?

Comment: No there are no transformations unless the 8 points happen to be in certain particular configurations (like a rotated cube, an scaled cube, etc.)

Comment: Mind we are talking about projective transformation, those that can be reasonably represented using matrices.

Comment: @sbabbi OK... Is there any ways to interpolate in a distorted box? i.e. We have some vector values on the eight points and we want to interpolate the value of a point inside the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not answering the original question since in the comment you said that you simply wanted to interpolate a function inside the cube, using the values at the 8 vertices.

So in order to do that, you can reason as follow:

1) [Split the cube in 6 tetrahedra](http://www.baumanneduard.ch/Splitting%20a%20cube%20in%20tetrahedras2.htm)

2) Find the tetrahedron that contains the point you want to interpolate

3) An irregular tetrahedron can be easily mapped to a regular one, that is you can easily obtain the generalized tetrahedral coordinates of a point. Check eq. 9-11 [here](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/AFEM.d/AFEM.Ch09.d/AFEM.Ch09.pdf).

4) Once you have the tetrahedral coordinates of your point, the interpolation is trivial (see previous link).

This is the easiest way I can think of, the big downside is that there are 13 ways to split a cube in tetrahedras, and this choice will produce (slightly) different results, especially if the cube is heavily deformed.  You should aim for a delaunay tetrahedralization of the cube to minimize this effect.

Also notice that the interpolated function defined in this way is continuous across the faces of the tetrahedra (but not differentiable).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the inverse of a [scaling matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_%28geometry%29#Matrix_representation) to the cube where **vx**, **vy** and **vz**
are the cube's spacial extents.

Comment: The first box is distorted! It means the side may not be parallel anymore. It may be rotated. We need something more than just a scale.

Comment: @mmostajab Then apply the inverse of the distortion matrix to it.

Comment: inverse of distortion is exactly what I need. I want to know how to compute the inverse of distortion?

Comment: @mmostajab Why don't you have it? Just keep track of all the transformations you apply.

Comment: I have not applied any transformation. I just have 8 points which shows a distorted box. I want to transform this box to a normal box. I am looking for that transformation.

Comment: @mmostajab This is not possible using matrices I suppose.

Comment: is there anyway to interpolate in a distorted box?

Comment: Yes! I can create the 4 faces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71113/discussion-between-axalo-and-mmostajab).